# Quoting an argument passed to a function

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have the following function:

```
print_argument <- function(vector) {
  message(substitute(vector))
}
```

This function does what I want for the most part, e.g.,

```
abc <- 1:3
print_argument(abc)

# output:
# abc
```

But it doesn't work for the following argument:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
col_name <- "a"
print_argument(df[[col_name]])

# output:
# [[dfcol_name
```

How would you update the function so that it also prints (**using the message function**) arguments like `df[[col_name]]` verbatim?

That is, how would you make it print (**using the message function**) the following: `df[[col_name]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `deparse` before wrapping with `message`

```
print_argument <- function(vector) {
  message(deparse(substitute(vector)))
 }

print_argument(df[[col_name]])
#df[[col_name]]

print_argument(abc)
#abc
```

---

When we get the substitute output, it is not a single string, and its components can be checked with `as.list`

```
print_argument <- function(vector) {
    as.list(substitute(vector))
   }
print_argument(df[[col_name]])
#[[1]]
#`[[`

#[[2]]
#df

#[[3]]
#col_name


print_argument(abc)
#[[1]]
#abc
```

Comment: What about ```quote```?

Comment: @Emer sorry didn't understand your question.  I showed an option that corrects the OP's code

Comment: @akrun This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!